# ConnectionService implementation for OutgoingCall

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, phone-call

I am trying to implement ConnectionService, PhoneAccount and PhoneAccountHandle inorder to get the disconnectCause for the disconnection of my outgoing call(E.g. User rejected the call, unreachable, etc.)
So far I have been able to initiate a call using customPhoneAccount but that phonecall never goes through and hence I am unable to get the response.

Here is the code which I have written uptill now:

register() is the method which is being called from my activity to register the phoneAccount:

```
public void register() {
    TelecomManager manager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE);
    PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
            new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                    MyConnectionService.class.getName()), "myConnectionServiceId");
    PhoneAccount.Builder builder = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "CustomAccount");
    builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER | PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER);
    PhoneAccount phoneAccount = builder.build();
    manager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
}
```

call()method which initiates the call:

```
 public void call() {
    TelecomManager manager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE);
    PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
            new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                    MyConnectionService.class.getName()), "myConnectionServiceId");
    Bundle test = new Bundle();
    test.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, phoneAccountHandle);
    manager.placeCall(Uri.parse("tel:" + "1212312312"), test);
}
```

Here is MyConnectionService:

```
public class MyConnectionService extends ConnectionService {

public static final String TAG = MyConnectionService.class.getName();
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "On Start");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public Connection onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    Connection connection = super.onCreateOutgoingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request);
    Log.d(TAG, connection.getDisconnectCause().getReason());
    return connection;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOutgoingConnectionFailed(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    if (request != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, request.toString());
    }
    super.onCreateOutgoingConnectionFailed(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request);
}
```

I have tried with different capabilities along with all options mentioned on other threads related to ConnectionService but couldn't get the desired result, can anybody help me in this ?

Comment: Were you able to implement it? I was only able to make a fake/dummy call using ConnectionService but I need to be able to make an actual call. Checked the Android source code and it looks like there are lots of things that need to be done. I know there should be a better way.

Comment: @artsylar: Nope, I couldn't make it work and i am not sure if things have changed in last 2 years or so but at that time it was evident that Android doesn't allow "to get the disconnectCause for the disconnection of my outgoing call"

Comment: @Saurabh7474 I am stuck to implement connectionService API. Could you please provide some example to integrate connectionService.

Comment: Uhm... maybe because `super.onCreateOutgoingConnection` returns a null?

Answer (score 6):

A few things:

1. You should not use the `PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER`, that has a special purpose which is not applicable to your use case and which requires special permissions.
2. Your `onCreateOutgoingConnection` method should not call the super version; that method is an blank method in the base `ConnectionService` class. Telecom calls your override of `onCreateOutgoingConnection` so that you can provide a new instance of Connection.

Take a look at the Android Open Source `TestConnectionService` class; it implements a simple `ConnectionService`:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm/+/master/testapps/src/com/android/server/telecom/testapps/TestConnectionService.java

Comment: Isn't the TestConnectionService for making a dummy/fake call only? I am also trying to implement our own Calling App using ConnectionService too. I would like my app to be able to make a real carrier call. Is it possible using ConnectionService class?

Comment: I recommended looking at TestConnectionService as an example of how to implement the API.
The ConnectionService API does not allow your app to place a real carrier call.  Its purpose is primarily to wrap the functionality of a VoIP calling solution so that the calls will appear in the device's dialer/phone app.
If you want to place calls you'd need permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE and can then use TelecomManager#placeCall to place an outgoing call.

Comment: Thank you @TGunn! If it doesn't allow your app to place a real carrier call, then is it possible to create your own calling app with added functionality like playing music during the call, etc.

Comment: @TGunn Could you please provide some example to implement connection service.

Comment: the sample code is very helpful, thanks @TGunn

Comment: @TGunn is there anyway i can use CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER i was to rely completly on androids functionality  to make the call, but all i need is the call back events so i can trigger things on my end. i cant find much documentation on how to use it.

Comment: @j2emanue, CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER is not intended for this use-case.  It is intended to support carriers which are providing services such as over the top wifi calling.  The API provides a means for the carrier's app to delegate a call to OTT WIFI calling where required, for example.   It sounds like you're interested in knowing the state of calls on the device; the IncallService API is intended for that purpose.

Comment: i built it using inCallService and it works but the problem is i need to use androids UI. this way is making me set an activity as the dialer, forcing me to have to create a UI. i want to completely reuse androids UI and i control the events. i dont want to draw my own UI. how can i do this @TGunn

Comment: @j2emanue that isn't a supported use case.  The purpose of the InCallService API is to support a UI replacement.  Monitoring and controlling call related events is restricted to the primary calling UI for performance and user privacy reasons.

Comment: @TGunn how can we disconnect other calls if there's a clash between normal and VoIP calls? the override methods in Connection class are not getting triggered, can you please help?